# VLOOKUP copies and paste existing value instead of looking up table

Tags: excel, vlookup

I'm having real difficulties with a VLOOKUP formula on an excel spreadsheet.  Instead of bringing back the correct values it appears to be copying and pasting the answer from the first cell.

Table 1 is:

```
uprn        Day and Week
10024239501 Friday 2
452061980   Friday 1
452026455   Thursday 1
452010090   Thursday 2
452015382   Wednesday 2
452034567   Wednesday 1
452058333   Tuesday 1
452033532   Tuesday 2
452047401   Monday 1
452060801   Monday 2
```

table 2 is

```
uprn        letter
10024239501 a
452061980   b
452026455   c
452010090   d
452015382   e
452034567   f
452058333   g
452033532   h
452047401   i
452060801   j
```

the vlookup formula i've used in table 1, column 3 is:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,$F$1:$G$10,2,FALSE)
```

When I then drag this formula down for the rest of the table it gives me the following:

```
uprn        day and week    letter
10024239501 Friday 2    a
452061980   Friday 1    a
452026455   Thursday 1  a
452010090   Thursday 2  a
452015382   Wednesday 2 a
452034567   Wednesday 1 a
452058333   Tuesday 1   a
452033532   Tuesday 2   a
452047401   Monday 1    a
452060801   Monday 2    a
```

I've made sure that cells are numbers and text in each table, but still it only appears to be working for the top value and then copying this result down for the rest of the table.

What I would expect in a correct VLOOKUP table would be:

```
uprn        day and week    letter
10024239501 Friday 2    a
452061980   Friday 1    b
452026455   Thursday 1  c
452010090   Thursday 2  d
452015382   Wednesday 2 e
452034567   Wednesday 1 f
452058333   Tuesday 1   g
452033532   Tuesday 2   h
452047401   Monday 1    i
452060801   Monday 2    j
```

Comment: Sounds like you have calculation set to manual?

Comment: Press `Alt + M + X + A` ... And then try again dragging the Formula down

Comment: Thank you - turns out the spreadsheet had formulas set to manual calculation.  Changing it to automatic solved the issue!